# transform a vector in dash vector in picture environment

Tags: diagrams

I have a picture environment to create a figure. I want to modify a vector in a dash vector.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{5cm}
\begin{picture}(1,1)(0,0)
\put(0,0){\vector(1,0){1}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

If it is possible with another environment that do note make me redraw the all figure it's fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a trial, since I believe that dashed lines can be generated only with `\multiput` etc. statements or loops.

The `vector` is rather dotted than dashed, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{5cm}
\begin{picture}(1,1)(0,0)
\linethickness{0.5pt}
\qbezier[100](0,0)(0.5,0.0)(0.98,0.0)
\put(0.98,0){\vector(1,0){0.02}}%
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice way to do it and perfect for my need :)

Answer (score 3):

Mandatory TikZ suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed,->,>=stealth] (0,0) -- (5cm,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've thought about TikZ however I've a full figure and it may be complicated to redraw it with TikZ. But thanks for your proposition :)

Comment: @RomainPicot You said it was fine with suggestions for other environments, if not I don't think I would have posted this answer.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn't so clear on my last sentance about the possible redraw of all the graphics

Answer (score 3):

A  `dashed vector` with the `curve2e` package, which is an extension of `pict2e`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{curve2e}
\usepackage{fp}%

\begin{document}

\setlength{\unitlength}{5cm}\linethickness{0.6pt}
\begin{picture}(1,1)(0,0)\FPmul{\endx}{0.975}{1}
\Dashline(0,0)(\endx,0){0.04}\put(1,0){\vector(1,0){0}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]